# Prevent initial page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to prevent AngularJS from doing anything on the initial page load?
When the user loads a page the initial content is served via PHP so AngularJS does not need to make a round-trip to load the content which is already there.

When I use `$locationChangeStart` and I `preventDefault()` on the event the initial content is removed and I'm left with a navigation bar and a an empty `ng-view` div..

Comment: If you dont need angular on page - do not add it. Have like welcome.php with link to your angular app.

Comment: I do need Angular on my page--just not on the initial load. I output the initial content so the page loads faster but when the user clicks a link on the page which directs to another page on **my** site, Angular needs to handle that click and change the route.

Comment: You may have angular pages host.com#state1, host.com#state2 and non-angular host.com/smth.html. And this will do exactly what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

If you want angular not to bootstrap initially, you can avoid writing ng-app on elements in your html, and then manually call angular.boostrap(document.getElementById("divId"),["yourModule"]) whenever you want it initialized.

Comment: Is this the only way to accomplish what I want? My current setup utilizes RequireJS to load all of my controllers etc... and AngularJS controls my navigation menu. Is there no way to just cancel loading the initial view?